convert a uint8 * to array in union
I'm doing my project and get into some trouble
I have an API and needs to put a uint8_t pointer in a union's array
struct {
   myunion union
   ...
} mystruct

union {
   uint8_t data[64];
   ...
} myunion

void myAPI(uint8_t *data)
{
   mystruct s;
   
   s.union->data[0] = 0x01;
   copy data to s.union->data without cover s.union->data[0];
}

How can I do as above?

How about memcpy  (from data to &(s.union->data[1])?

Well what else is inside the union apart from the uint8_t array? There must be something of relevance there or there's no making sense of the code. Probably a pointer member if that's what you need? Or do you mean to copy the pointed-at data, which probably makes more sense?

Neither your struct or union definitions compile. Please show some effort and make sure that the code you are presenting is syntactically valid.

What is your "project"? What is the task you're assigned to do? What is the underlying problem you think such a copy would solve? Why can't you "cover s.union->data[0]"?

A structure cannot have a member named union since that is a keyword in the C language. Supposing, for example, the member is actually called member, if you want to copy the memory that data points to into the memory after s.member->data[0], so that the first element is not overwritten, you can copy it using memcpy:
memcpy(&s.member->data[1], data, NumberOfBytesToCopy);
If you want to copy the actual pointer (as your text says “put a uint8_t pointer in a union's array”) rather than the memory it points to, you can copy the pointer itself:
memcpy(&s.member->data[1], &data, sizeof data);
